# how get checkbox treeview checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use Jquery popup on button click....and make asp tree hard code in popup body ....

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="headerpopup">

        <asp:Label ID="lblPopupHeader" runat="server" CssClass="msg" Text="Select Fields" />

        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnHideModal" runat="server" CssClass="close" 

                        OnClientClick="$('#divSimplePopup').hideModal(); return false;" />

    </div>

    <div class="bodyAnd">

        <div class="body" style="height: 250px; overflow: auto;">

        <asp:TreeView ID="someTree" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"  >
<Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Root"> 
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Branch">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
        </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Root">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Leaf" />
    </asp:TreeNode>
</Nodes>
```

```
        <div class="foot">
        <div class="footerpopup">

            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="40px" CssClass="add-but" OnClientClick="treeClick();"  />

            <asp:Button ID="btnCncl" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="add-but"

                        OnClientClick="$('#divSimplePopup').hideModal(); return false;" />

        </div>
     </div>


</div>
```

I want Check box value on codebehind and server side ....any idea how i got check box value on OK button???

Comment: Where is the checkbox ? I cannot see that anywhere...

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1866219.aspx/1?how+get+checkbox+treeview+checked+value